# No stamp when going from India to Glasgow through Dublin

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, ireland, common-travel-area

I was going to Glasgow via Dublin from India carrying tier 5 UK visa for 2 months student exchange. Immigration officials didn't stamp my entry neither in Dublin or in Glasgow.
Will it be problem? Even though I asked regarding the immigration formalities at Glasgow, they told you have to do it from Dublin and in Dublin no customs or immigration official asked for it. Kindly let me know if this will be problem in the future. I will be returning the same way (via Dublin) to India in April 2.

Comment: Who did you ask in Glasgow? IIRC, UK+IE nationals don't need to go through immigration when moving between the two countries [due to the Common Travel area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area), but all others do, so you should've gone through immigration in Glasgow (even though most people wouldn't have)

Comment: @Gagravarr The way I remember it, there isn't any clear separation, at least on arrival in Dublin and when crossing by ferry or at a land border (don't know about Glasgow). Some people don't have the right to cross the border or might need stamps but they have to make sure they follow the rules themselves because the checks are minimal, at least on the Irish side.

Comment: In many cases, if you need to pass through immigration within the CTA, you need to actively seek someone out. Just because most people on the plane/ferry didn't need to, doesn't excuse you for not doing so, at least in the eyes of the immigration rules...

Comment: Now I am Glasgow and I dont have a UK entry stamp. Should I go to visa / embassy office to report this? I have preserved my boarding passes. Kindly let me know what should I do to avoid future problems

Comment: I know it's been quite a long time since the time you posted this. I was wondering, did you have any issues? I am travelling from Bangladesh via Dublin to Glasgow. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Because the UK has left the EU since this question was posted, I would consider this question and its answers to be stale. @Mazdia should ask a new question. By the way, I'm a US citizen and flew Boston to Dublin to Edinburgh around 2015 and would not rely on that experience to understand the current travel situation.

Answer (score 10):

You've run into a very common problem and one that's documented in numerous places regarding *Tier 4* visas but it also applies to [Tier 5](http://eap.ucop.edu/Documents/_forms/1213/United_Kingdom/UK_SPI/SPI%20Visa%20Intructions.pdf).  As you've noted, entry from Ireland will not cause you to enter via UK immigration. As a result no one will have activated your visa and you will be in the UK technically illegally - the Irish can't do it, and the local UK guys in the airport generally won't do it because you're entering from within the Common Travel Area.

If anyone tries to review whether you're in the country legally this may indeed cause you issues.  I would suggest contacting your sponsor or the [UK Visas and Immigration contact centre](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi/visas-and-settlement) as soon as possible to get it sorted out.

*UK Visas and Immigration contact centre details:*

> Telephone: 0300 123 2241
>
> Monday to Thursday, 9am to 4.45pm
>
> Friday, 9am to 4.30pm